# How to test a controller method in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-jasmine

I am attempting to test a controller in my angular app. Whenever I call the `$controller` method I get back an empty object.

Relevant test

```
describe("myCtrl", function() {

beforeEach(module("myMod"));

var myCtrl, scope;

beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    myCtrl = $controller('myCtrl', {$scope: scope});
}));

it("$scope.compute", function() {
    expect(myCtrl.compute(1,1,1)).toBe(1);
});
});
```

Relevant parts of controller:

```
.controller('myCtrl', ["$scope","serviceA", "serviceB", function($scope, serviceA, serviceB){

    $scope.compute = function compute(a, b, c) {
        return serviceA.calc(a, b, c);
    };
}])
```

Whenever I run my test, I get an error that `undefined is not a function`.

If I `console.log(JSON.stringify(myCtrl))` before I call the method, it shows that `myCtrl` is an empty object(`{}`).

I believe that my problem is with the call to `$controller` or perhaps I need to set my scope differently.

***Summary: How can I make a unit test so that calls a method inside my controller?***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function/method is not in the controller, but in the `$scope`, so it should be:

```
it("$scope.compute", function() {
    expect(scope.compute(1,1,1)).toBe(1);
});
```

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense now.